# How do I stop my AutoCompleteTextView dropdown from scrolling over my AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-design-library

I have a `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` with an anchor which is further down than the `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`. This is by design and can not be changed. When I scroll on the dropdown, the dropdown moves up and on top of the `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

[image]

Is that the way it should work?

This is my code:

**Main activity xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.autocompletetest.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.87"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/anchor"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        android:hint="entervalue"
        android:inputType="textUri"
        android:popupBackground="@null"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autocomplete"
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:background="#aaaaaa"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main activity java:**

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView auto = (AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
        auto.setAdapter(adapter);
```

EDIT: I should mention I saw this behavior on Marshmallow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to be happening because of `android:popupBackground="@null"`

Answer (score 3):

Remove --> android:popupBackground="@null"
from AutoCompleteTextView

and than check it.

Comment: Yeap, that's what the answer says.

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation it says that:

> View to anchor the auto-complete dropdown to. If not specified, the
>   text view itself is used.

Do you need your custom anchor at all? I imagine the default doesn't have this behavior likely caused by your relative layout.

Comment: Unfortunately the design calls for the dropdown to be a bit further down from where the `AutoCompleteTextView` is at.

Comment: I would switch to a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation then. There is no need for a RelativeLayout here that I see.

Comment: The exact same issue happens with `LinearLayout`. Also if I make the dropdown show up above the anchor then the issue where it scrolls on top happens with the toolbar and status bar. The issue is actually happening because of `android:popupBackground="@null"`